# Codeigniter redirect appends to the last URL

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm trying to redirect a user when they successfully log in:

```
if (!$userID) {
    $this->session->set_flashdata('login_error', TRUE);
} else {
    $this->session->set_userdata(array(
        'logged_in' => TRUE,
        'userID' => $userID,
        'username' => $username
    ));
    redirect("welcome_page");
}
```

However, the new link is like this:

[image]

I want it to be `localhost/pasaj/`, I don't know but it appends to the former url.

My base_url as declared in config.php

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/pasaj/';
```

This is the opening tag of the login form:

```
<form method="post" id="formSubmit" name="fSubmit" action=<?php base_url(); ?>"kayit/kayitOnay/">
```

However, it makes the url like this:

[image]

Comment: Can you please clarify your question? You're currently redirecting users to the "welcome" page after login? How is the `<a>` tag and image generated? Please expand on what you're trying to do.

Comment: sorry i edit my question

Answer (score 4):

<strike>First off, I'm not sure why you are wrapping your code in `![ ][1]`. I can't imagine what the purpose of wrapping your code in an array would be, and I don't think it's helping your problem.</strike>

I believe @Eric Cope is right, your `$config['base_url']` in application/config/config.php is probably incorrect. You might have typed it as `$config['base_url'] = 'localhost/pasaj'`, but you want it to look more like `$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost:81/pasaj/'`. This may be what's causing your redirect to append the URL to your existing request rather than request the full, absolute URL.

Comment: The `![ ][1]` was a result of failed code formatting in the post itself.

Answer (score 0):

I think CI is reading your redirect as a relative URI. Try redirecting to `"/welcome_page"`.

Answer (score 0):

Check your URL in configs/config.php. Also, double check that "welcome_page" isn't redirecting if a session value is incorrect. The redirect there may be to blame.